# Map is showing nothing

Tags: swift

[image: picture]   I am trying to set up the map view programmatically and i have set up the constraints down below but when i run the simulator it is just showing a blank screen. I want to pin the map view to the top,bottom,left,right in the view.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.view.backgroundColor = .white
        configureScreen()
    }
    
 
    
    let map: MKMapView = {
        let map = MKMapView()
        map.backgroundColor = .black
        return map
    }()
    
    func configureScreen(){
        
        view.addSubview(map)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            map.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor,constant: 100),
            map.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor,constant: 0),
            map.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor,constant: 0),
            map.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor,constant: 0)
        ])
            
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: You have probably constraint warnings in your console. Usually it's a good idea to look at warnings and solve them :)

Answer (score 1):

Because you forgot to say

```
map.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```